# Drawing shapes in css responsively

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I have a 'div' with slight curve at the top. I tried and achieved using border. 
But my concern is its not responsive. How to make it responsive. Any idea? Here is the code which i tried have a look at this.

```
<div></div>

div {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    background:green;
    height:80px;
    overflow:hidden
  }
div:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: 0;
    right: 50%;
    border: 298px solid transparent;
    top: 0;
    border-top: 13px solid #fff;
}
```

Also refer the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qvbv8rt/)

[image]

Comment: By responsive do you mean that the cut at the top should always reach its max depth at the center of the div and be zero depth at the left/right side? Also, what is the background of the element? Is it always a solid color (or) does it have a gradient/image fill?

Comment: S ur right.try resizing the window.since the border has a fixed width.it is not touching its parent end to end. Is there is any workaround for this to stay in same size even when the browser is resized.

And of course It will be having a gradient fill...

Comment: In your example the cut area has a white color? Can that area be a solid color or does it have to show the background of page (I mean, should it be transparent cut)?

Comment: let it be white color. For demo purpose i made it white. Actually it will be a gradient

Comment: Depending on what you actually need there would be a difference in how the shape can be created. Anyway I will try to give you solutions for a transparent cut.

Comment: @Harry i have added the image...need the cut exactly like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using CSS Gradients + Transforms:**

One way to achieve this shape with a responsive cut at the top would be to use two skewed pseudo elements, add the background to the pseudo-elements alone and not the parent element.

Since, the pseudo-elements are half the width of their parent element, the `linear-gradient` fill that is required on the parent should also be divided into two halves and assigned to the 2 pseudo-elements.

One potential drawback of this approach is that the depth of the cut will increase if height of the parent div increases.

```css
.shape {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.shape:after,
.shape:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  top: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.shape:before {
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, gold);
  transform: skewY(2deg);
  transform-origin: left top;
}
.shape:after {
  right: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, gold, crimson);
  transform: skewY(-2deg);
  transform-origin: right top;
}
body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, sandybrown, chocolate);
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class='shape'></div>
```

**Using CSS Clip-path:** (poor browser support)

Another approach would be to make use of CSS `clip-path`. This, in my opinion, would be the perfect option as there needs to be no gradient manipulation (like dividing into half), the depth of the cut will not change even if the height of the `div` increases etc. But unfortunately it has poor browser support.

```css
.shape {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 50% 14px, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, gold, crimson);
}
body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, sandybrown, chocolate);
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class='shape'></div>
```

**Using SVG Clip-path:** (better browser support)

Another approach would be to make use of SVG `clip-path`. This has better browser support than its CSS counterpart but unfortunately, here the depth of the cut will change as the dimensions change.

```css
.shape {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipper);
  clip-path: url(#clipper);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, gold, crimson);
}
body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, sandybrown, chocolate);
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipper" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path d="M0,0 0.5,0.07 1,0 1,1 0,1z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div class='shape'></div>
```

Alternately, we can do the same using a SVG `path` or `polygon` element (instead of `clip-path`) and position it absolutely within the parent container also, but it would have the same limitation as the SVG clip-path (that is, depth of cut will increase if dimensions change because the values are in fractions of parent container's size and not in fixed length).